# The desire and expectation to see a situation escalate

Tags: social-psychology, sentiment-analysis

Does this phenomenon have a name?

When there is a diagreement or conflict or scandal, sometimes instead of wanting the issue to be solved and left behind I want it to escalate and expand.

This can be for mere "entertainment" or breaking routine. Or not to see the people involved in it free from complications.

Does this have a name?

Answer (score 2):

Overall, the described phenomenon sounds like a classic case of [Schadenfreude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schadenfreude). In this emotion, a person takes pleasure in seeing the misfortune of others, particularly those of an out-group. The essence in this emotion seems to be a relative rise in one's perceived well-being as compared to another's predicament. From Wikipedia:

> [**Schadenfreude**] is the experience of pleasure, joy, or self-satisfaction that comes from learning of or witnessing the troubles, failures, or humiliation of another. [...] *Schadenfreude* is borrowed from German. It is a compound of *Schaden*, "damage/harm", and *Freude*, "joy".

An important distinction ought to be given here to contrast with [sadism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sadistic_personality_disorder). In this personality trait, satisfaction is found not only in *observing*, but also in actions *promoting*, the suffering of others. Moreover, in Schadenfreude, the focus is on social-status and circumstances, whereas in sadism, the focus is on pain and suffering. From Wikipedia:

> [**Sadism**] involves deriving pleasure through others undergoing discomfort or pain. [...] Individuals possessing sadistic personalities tend to display recurrent aggression and cruel behavior. Sadism can also include the use of emotional cruelty, purposefully manipulating others through the use of fear, and a preoccupation with violence.

A more indirect factor which could in theory modulate both of the above is [sensation seeking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensation_seeking). In this personality trait, a person may feel incomplete without higher levels of stimulation. From Wikipedia:

> **Sensation seeking** is a personality trait defined by the search for experiences and feelings, that are "varied, novel, complex and intense", and by the readiness to "take physical, social, legal, and financial risks for the sake of such experiences." [...] [Marvin Zuckerman]'s research has found that high sensation seekers tend to seek high levels of stimulation in their daily lives.